(Python) Error for getting Kivy Label ID: AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'. Did you mean: '__setattr__'?
Consider following Code:
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

class MyApp(App):  
    def build(self):    
           
        sm.add_widget(InputScreen(name="Input"))
        return sm 

Builder.load_string(''' 
<InputScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            id: name_label
            text: "x"
''')    

class InputScreen(Screen):
    def press(self):
        name = "Trevor"
        self.ids.name_Label.text = "Is your name"+name+" ?"       #Error line


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()


When I am executing the code, I am getting the Error AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'getattr'. Did you mean: 'setattr'? in line(see comment).
Did I handle the ID getting wrong? What is the fix?

Can you include the full error/traceback message you are getting? Your code doesn't seem like it can run as-is, so I'm not able to reproduce.

The error you are getting is because you are trying to access the name_label widget with the name_Label attribute, but you made a typo. In Kivy language the IDs are case-sensitive, so name_label and not name_Label.
self.ids.name_label.text = "Is your name " + name + " ?"


Thanks, you saved my mind with such a simple mistake :)
